# How to add a domain to my website which is hosted in Ubuntu VPS?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns, server, networking

I bought a domain from Bluehost and added A record pointing to my VPS IP at my domain registrar. I don't know what is virtual host? and how to configure it? and why should we configure it?

I am Junior Backend Developer and I want to learn servers and hostings also. So I bought both domain and server from same service so it was not that much difficult. That's why I bought domain from another service and VPS from another service.

Now I'm going to create a WordPress on my VPS and want to add domain to my WordPress site. add domain to VPS site and also how to add multiple domains in multiple sites hosted in single VPS,

[image: A Records]

[image: NS Record]

Comment: When you [asked this at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73684044/how-to-add-a-domain-to-my-website-which-is-hosted-in-ubuntu-vps), I asked you to edit it to include more information.  However, you didn't include enough information.  You say you don't know what a virtual host is, but how about the other information?

Comment: Where do your `NS` records point? Where did you add the `A` record? What web server are you running on the VPS? How have you configured the virtual hosts on it?

Comment: 1. Currently my `NS` records pointing at my VPS IP address.
2. I added the `A` record in my dns management zone which is in my domain registrant login
3. I have to install Apache server for making wordpress site. 2 days back i installed but then i changed os and tried so i ahve to install again
4. I am not sure whether I configured virtual host or not i dont know about it

pls iam a newbie please teach

Comment: `NS` records should point to the name servers of your DNS host, not to your VPS IP address.  The `A` records at your DNS host should then point to your VPS IP address.  Can you say which company you are using for your DNS host?  Can you [edit] your question to add screenshots of this configuration?

Comment: Apache's name-based virtual host documentation is here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html  You'll need to set up configuration in Apache for your domain names using virtual hosts if you haven't already done so.

Comment: Sorry, `NS` records already has name servers of dns and `A` record is pointing to my VPS IP Address. I bought domain from Bluehost they itself providing DNS Managment. btw I am adding few screenshots now...

Comment: Now i have configured virtual host on port `80` and installed wordpress also. If I go to my vps ip it is showing the main page i.e `http://185.210.144.130/` but if i enter into `need4itcomputers.com` the site is down. I have also added `A record` to my vps ip address and it has been more than 1day. Please help and teach me sir.

Comment: The command line `dig NS need4itcomputers.com` returns no results and `whois need4itcomputers.com` says the domain in parked.  Have you edited your `NS` records at your domain registrar to point to bluehost's name servers?

Comment: NS records were already there and is active i have added the screenshot of ns record please find it

Comment: Whois also says your domain registrar is www.publicdomainregistry.com.  You need to set the NS records there, the screenshot you have is from bluehost.

Comment: oh what should i do now? i should go to www.publicdomainregistry.com and add NS record ? how can i find NS Record ? pls tell sir

Comment: According to this article https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/updating-name-servers-at-public-domain-registry-pdr you probably bought through a reseller and need to use their API.

Comment: Not useful sir. NS record already correct. any other way?

Comment: The NS record is not set correctly.  If you actually bought the domain through bluehost, you need to contact their tech support I think.

Comment: Ok sir. But what I did is simply doing "domain transfer" in my server provider. i.e., from Bluehost to Hostinger. Lets see what happen.. Btw, Thanks sir